# A question about linear combination

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is to show

> Given a non-zero vector u and a set of non-zero vectors $D=\{v_1,v_2,…,v_n\}$, show that $u$ is not a linear combination of $D$ if $u⋅v_i=0$ for all of $i=1,2,…,n$.

It is easy for $n=1$, if $u=k_1 v_1$ for some $k_1≠0$, then $u⋅v_1=k_1 v_1^2=0$ implies $v_1=0$, contradicting with condition that $v_1≠0$. But I get stuck as I try to proceed the induction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose to the contrary that there exist $a_1,a_2,\dots, a_n$ such that $u=a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\cdots+a_n v_n$. Then 
$$u\cdot u=a_1(u\cdot v_1)+a_2(u\cdot v_2)+\cdots +a_n(u\cdot v_n)=0.$$
It follows that $u$ is the zero vector.

Answer (score 1):

Try the proof by contraposition

If $u$ is a linear combination of $D$, then $u=\sum_{i=1}^n k_iv_i$ with $k_i\in\mathbb{R}$ and, at least, one of the $k_i\ne 0$. Let $i_0\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ be such that $k_{i_0}\ne0$. Then:
$$u\cdot v_{i_0} = \dots$$

Try to continue from there.

Answer (score 0):

the fact that $u\cdot v_i=0 \quad \forall i$ means hat $u$ is orthogonal to all $v_i$, so it is not in the vector space spanned by the $v_i$, i.e. it is not a linear combination of the $v_i$.